# Trouble getting Single shot multibox detector to run

Tags: linux, machine-learning, import, python-import, osgeo

So sorry if I am phrasing this question poorly, but I'm generally unfamiliar with machine learning/importing, and don't really know what's causing this error.  Essentially, I'm trying to run this https://github.com/aurotripathy/ssd-spacenet/blob/ssd/spacenet/README.md.  I cloned the directory, and am following the readme.  I thought that I installed all of the dependencies, but for some reason I keep getting an error that implies otherwise.  This is the error:

```
$ ./gen-pascalvoc-format.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./gen-pascalvoc-format.py", line 8, in <module>
    from spaceNet import geoTools as gT
  File "/home/ssd-spacenet/spacenet/utilities/python/spaceNet/geoTools.py", line 1, in <module>
    from osgeo import gdal, osr, ogr
  File "/home/installations/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/osgeo/__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
    _gdal = swig_import_helper()
  File "/home/installations/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/osgeo/__init__.py", line 17, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_gdal', fp, pathname, description)
ImportError: libjpeg.so.8: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

The __init__.py file looks like this:

```
# __init__ for osgeo package.

# making the osgeo package version the same as the gdal version:
from sys import version_info
if version_info >= (2,6,0):
    def swig_import_helper():
        from os.path import dirname
        import imp
        fp = None
        try:
            fp, pathname, description = imp.find_module('_gdal', [dirname(__file__)])
        except ImportError:
            import _gdal
            return _gdal
        if fp is not None:
            try:
                _mod = imp.load_module('_gdal', fp, pathname, description)
            finally:
                fp.close()
            return _mod
    _gdal = swig_import_helper()
    del swig_import_helper
else:
    import _gdal

__version__ = _gdal.__version__ = _gdal.VersionInfo("RELEASE_NAME")
```

Again, sorry that this is such a poorly formed question, but where should I start?

Comment: `libjpeg.so.8: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`. Do you have that, or any, version of libjpeg installed?

Comment: @MarkPlotnick 

Yes I do.  

    `$ ldconfig -p | grep libjpeg`  
            `libjpeg.so.62 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib64/libjpeg.so.62`  
            `libjpeg.so (libc6,x86-64) => /lib64/libjpeg.so`